# Convert query ToListAsync in separate method, not ActionResult

Tags: entity-framework-6

I am trying to 'convert' a query to List while using async to retrieve the values to a list and return the NewsListViewModel to my controller as a success or failure like so:

```
var model = await db.News.Where(n => n.newsPublished == false
                && n.newsTitle.Contains(query)
                || n.newsDescription.Contains(query)).
                OrderBy(n => n.newsCreatedDate).Select(n => new List<NewsListViewModel>
                {
                    NewsCreatorFName = n.Profile.profileFirstName,
                    NewsCreatorLName = n.Profile.profileLastName,
                    NewsID = n.newsID,
                    NewsCreatorID = n.userID,
                    NewsTitle = n.newsTitle,
                    CreatedDate = n.newsCreatedDate
                })
                .ToListAsync();
```

or like this:

```
public static async Task<List<NewsListViewModel>> GetAllNotPublished(string query)
    {
        if (query != "" && query != null)
        {

            var model = (from n in db.News
                         where n.newsPublished == false && n.newsTitle.Contains(query)
                         || n.newsDescription.Contains(query)
                         orderby n.newsCreatedDate
                         select new NewsListViewModel
                         {
                             NewsCreatorFName = n.Profile.profileFirstName,
                             NewsCreatorLName = n.Profile.profileLastName,
                             NewsID = n.newsID,
                             NewsCreatorID = n.userID,
                             NewsTitle = n.newsTitle,
                             CreatedDate = n.newsCreatedDate
                         });


            return await model.ToListAsync();

        }
        else
        {
            var model = (from n in db.News
                         where n.newsPublished == false
                         orderby n.newsCreatedDate
                         select new NewsListViewModel
                         {
                             NewsCreatorFName = n.Profile.profileFirstName,
                             NewsCreatorLName = n.Profile.profileLastName,
                             NewsID = n.newsID,
                             NewsCreatorID = n.userID,
                             NewsTitle = n.newsTitle,
                             CreatedDate = n.newsCreatedDate
                         });

            return await model.ToListAsync();

        }

    }
```

I am probably going about this bass akwards and WAAAAY wrong but I have been battling with this for hours now trying to figure it out and can't find any examples that look similar.
One thing is that I can return either one just fine if it is in the ActionResult which is strange to me. This below works just fine, but I don't want it in the ActionResult. I would like to have the list retrieval portion in a separate method.
Thanks in advance for any help.

```
public async Task<ActionResult> PublishList(string query)
    {

        if (query != "" && query != null)
        {

            var model = (from n in db.News
                            where n.newsPublished == false && n.newsTitle.Contains(query)
                            || n.newsDescription.Contains(query)
                            orderby n.newsCreatedDate
                            select new NewsListViewModel
                            {
                                NewsCreatorFName = n.Profile.profileFirstName,
                                NewsCreatorLName = n.Profile.profileLastName,
                                NewsID = n.newsID,
                                NewsCreatorID = n.userID,
                                NewsTitle = n.newsTitle,
                                CreatedDate = n.newsCreatedDate
                            });


            return View(await model.ToListAsync());

        }
        else
        {
            var model = (from n in db.News
                            where n.newsPublished == false
                            orderby n.newsCreatedDate
                            select new NewsListViewModel
                            {
                                NewsCreatorFName = n.Profile.profileFirstName,
                                NewsCreatorLName = n.Profile.profileLastName,
                                NewsID = n.newsID,
                                NewsCreatorID = n.userID,
                                NewsTitle = n.newsTitle,
                                CreatedDate = n.newsCreatedDate
                            });


            return View(await model.ToListAsync());

        }


    }
```